# Black artifacts on screen in the VR One demo scene on Galaxy S5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vrone

When i build the VR One demo scene in Unity 5.1.2f to my Galaxy S5 i get the artifacts you can see on the images below:

[Black Artifacts 1](http://spike.twisted-artwork.de/stack/vr1_artifact_1.jpg)

[Black Artifacts 2](http://spike.twisted-artwork.de/stack/vr1_artifact_3.jpg)

The first image shows the artifacts i get when i just start the app in landscape mode and force it to stay in landscape. If i allow rotation to portrait i get something like on the second image in portrait and it gets even worse when rotating back (Cant post three links...).

When i turn off the distortion everything is fine but thats not an option for the final app.

I also modified the shader to give out only solid colors and even if i just write out solid green, i get the black artifacts.

I created an empty project and imported the package you can download [here](http://bitbucket.org/vrone/unity3d). I already get the artifacts without changing anything.

Any ideas what could cause this? My guess would be some memory problem...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Good question.  Can you include some source code and/or configuration so we can see where the issue might be coming from?

Comment: I created an empty Projekt and imported the package you can download here: https://bitbucket.org/vrone/unity3d  I already get the artifacts without changing anything.

Comment: I can not narrow it down to a specific line of code or file, sorry.

Comment: That's a good example to include.  Hopefully some mobile unity experts can weigh in.

Comment: Maybe this can help to narrow it down a bit:

- Varying the standard quality settings can make the problem disappear or the pattern change. Unfortunately i can not just let it run on the highest setting as that will result in a too low fps count.
- I can produce similar problems using the google cardboard sdk (also with the demo scene that comes with the sdk) but the pattern is larger and i can only see one of the two stereo views.